# h2 command line returns (data is partially truncated)

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to run following query from `myTable` to H2

```
select * from MYTABLE;
```

Table Schema

```
sql> show columns from mytable;
FIELD             | TYPE                    | NULL | KEY | DEFAULT
UNIQUE_JOB_NAME   | VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(256) | NO   |     | NULL
UNIQUE_STEP_NAME  | VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(256) | YES  |     | NULL
OBJECT_CLASS_NAME | VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(256) | NO   |     | NULL
OBJECT_NAME       | VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(256) | NO   |     | NULL
OBJECT_DATA       | VARBINARY(2147483647)   | NO   |     | NULL
```

Result Returned

```
sql> select * from mytable;
UNIQUE_JOB_NAME           | UNIQUE_STEP_NAME | OBJECT_CLASS_NAME       | OBJECT_NAME             | OBJECT_DATA
someValue                 | null             | someValueJobData        |        someValueJobData        |  aced00057372004d636f6d2e656d632e636c6f75645f64722e6364722e636f6d6d6f6e732e636f6d6d6f6e5f6d6f64656c73
(data is partially truncated)
(1 rows, 2 ms)
```

command to connect to H2

```
java -cp h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Shell  -url "jdbc:h2:path/to/h2/mydb" -user randomuser -password randompass
```

Is their a way to ask h2-cli to not truncate the result data?

Comment: Have you tried using the web console?

Comment: I can't use web console, Its server machine I can just use SSH.

Comment: And what is actually truncated?

Comment: The OBJECT_DATA field is truncated.

Comment: What do you want to do with that data?
Why not build a very simple Java program which gets the data that you need and does what you need?

Comment: @ShaileshSuryawanshi - Did you find a solution around for this problems?

Answer (score -1):

in the h2 console set:
sql> maxwidth 10000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).